# How to capture the event whenever the items inside a listview are checked

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm developing a plugin in QGIS 2.8.2 using Pyqt 4.
Well the idea is using the processing 'qgis:extractbylocation' from the QGIS algorithm provider to capture the studied area

```
# Récupérer tous les iris qui s'intersectent avec la zone d'étude
res = processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', irisLayer, layerZone, u'intersects', 0, None)

# Créer une couche vector issue de l'extraction des IRIS dans la zone
ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer = QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT'], "IRIS dans la zone d'etude", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer)

# Définir un ecodage Windows compatible avec le français
ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer.setProviderEncoding(u'iso-8859-1')

# Modifier l'encoage
ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'iso-8859-1')

# Vérifier que le couche est valide sinon afficher que la couche est erronée
if not ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Then showing the results on a listview:

```
ObjectifVilleExtract.features = ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer.getFeatures()
ObjectifVilleExtract.model = QStandardItemModel(ObjectifVilleExtract.features)
for feature in ObjectifVilleExtract.features:
    item = QStandardItem(feature['nom_iris'])
    item.setCheckable(True)
    ObjectifVilleExtract.model.appendRow(item)
    self.dlg.listView_3.setModel(ObjectifVilleExtract.model)
    self.dlg.listView_3.show()
```

Now I want to capture checked item on the listview, to apply on its the following processes :

```
iter = ObjectifVilleExtract.features.getFeatures()
for feature in iter :
    q1 = "SELECT nom_com FROM france_full_data.contours_iris WHERE code_iris='" + feature['code_iris'] + "' "
```

I tried to use the following code :

```
for feature in ObjectifVilleExtract.features:
    while ObjectifVilleExtract.model.item(feature['nom_iris']) :
        if ObjectifVilleExtract.model.item(feature['nom_iris']).ischecked():
            ObjectifVilleExtract.iter = ObjectifVilleExtract.irisLayer.getFeatures()
            irisTab=[]
            for feature in ObjectifVilleExtract.iter :
                q1 = "SELECT nom_com FROM france_full_data.contours_iris WHERE code_iris='" + feature['code_iris'] + "' "
```

the result is empty !

Comment: And here comes the obvious question: Why are you developing for an outdated version which isn't supported anymore?

Comment: i'm doing an intership in an agency where they're using this version . So i'm obliged to develop for the 2.8.2 version of qgis even if it's oudated